# AngularJS - Parameter binding in controllers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, visual-studio-2013, angularjs-directive

I've got the following code sample and apparently I once again lack some background information.

When I use the `greet` directive, there is a binding happening on the controller level. For some reason it binds the element and the attribute values of the element to those corresponding variables (`$attr`, `$element`).

Is there a list with all the existing bindings which exist for the controllers?

I've done some research, but couldn't come up with anything in this direction.

### directives.js

```
angular.module('TodoApp.directives', []).    
    directive('greet', function () {
    return {
        template: '<h2>Greetings from {{from}} to {{to}}<h2>',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.from = $attrs.from;
            $scope.to = $attrs.greet;
        }
    };
});
```

### list.html

```
....
<div greet="Test1" from="Test2"></div>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directive controllers have some special bindings. You can find them in the docs of the `$compile` service ([here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)), search for "controller". Repeating here for completeness:

> The controller is injectable (and supports bracket notation) with the following locals:
>
> - `$scope` - Current scope associated with the element
> - `$element` - Current element
> - `$attrs` - Current attributes object for the element
> - `$transclude` - A transclude linking function pre-bound to the correct transclusion scope. The scope can be overridden by an optional first argument. `function([scope], cloneLinkingFn)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is  called *Dependency Injection*. Rather than having a fixed parameter list, Angular uses a DI container to inject the parameter when you need it. For example, if you need the $http service, just add it as a parameter - the order of the parameters does not matter.

The type of parameters you can inject are constants, values, factories, services, and providers.

Some are available to you 'out-of-the-box' from the Angular library: 
[Look here for Angular Providers and Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/api)

Others, you get from third-party modules, or modules that you develop  yourself.